# Rich-snippets - Double movie authors

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets

I did not understand how to behave in the case there were multiple items of the same type, as for the writers of a movie.
I have to repeat itemprop="author" for each writer or i can include them in a single div?

```
<div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <span itemprop="name"><a href="#">Cesare Frugoni</a></span>
    <span itemprop="name"><a href="#">Enrico Vanzina</a></span>
</div>
```

or

```
<div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <span itemprop="name"><a href="#">Enrico Vanzina</a></span>
</div>
<div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <span itemprop="name"><a href="#">Cesare Frugoni</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain more what this is in reference to? (Google search? If so, adding the [tag:google-search] tag will make many more tag followers aware than just [tag:rich-snippets]).

Comment: it's just a matter of syntax.. I added another tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter is right. The first snippet means that your person have two names (which is not so uncommon situation really). You can check it using [Google](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) or [Yandex](http://webmaster.yandex.ru/microtest.xml) validators. They  will give you smth like this

```
person
itemType = http://schema.org/Person
name = Cesare Frugoni
name = Enrico Vanzina
```

And you (I believe) need

```
person
itemType = http://schema.org/Person
name = Enrico Vanzina

person
itemType = http://schema.org/Person
name = Cesare Frugoni
```

Schema.org provides good example for this case at [schema.org/Movie](http://schema.org/Movie) .

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">

<h1 itemprop="name">Pirates of the Carribean: On Stranger Tides (2011)</h1>
<span itemprop="description">Jack Sparrow and Barbossa embark on a quest to
 find the elusive fountain of youth, only to discover that Blackbeard and
 his daughter are after it too.</span>
Director:
 <div itemprop="director" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<span itemprop="name">Rob Marshall</span>
</div>
Writers:
 <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<span itemprop="name">Ted Elliott</span>
</div>
<div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<span itemprop="name">Terry Rossio</span>
</div>
, and 7 more credits
Stars:
 <div itemprop="actor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<span itemprop="name">Johnny Depp</span>,
 </div>
<div itemprop="actor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<span itemprop="name">Penelope Cruz</span>,
</div>
<div itemprop="actor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<span itemprop="name">Ian McShane</span>
</div>
</div>
```

BTW there were a lot of discussions around cardinality of schema.org properties. If you're interested in details you can read corresponding materials: [ISSUE](http://www.w3.org/2011/webschema/track/issues/5) at tracker and [W3C Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/Singularity) page.

And I personally follow the rule stated by Guha:

> Right now, it is always allowed to have multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are both correct. Imdb use frist syntax.

```
<div itemprop="creator" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"> 
    <h4 class="inline">Writers:</h4>
    <a href="#" itemprop='url'><span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">Cesare Frugoni</span></a>
    <a href="#" itemprop='url'><span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">Steno</span></a>
</div>
```